# Ordenar en MySql varchar de números y signos como INT

Tags: php, mysql, ordenar

Tengo una columna de mi tabla que es de tipo varchar pero es para un orden. El formato de esta columna es por ejemplo:

1 (1/2),
1 (2/2),
2,
3 (1/3),
3 (2/3),
3 (3/3),
4,
5,
…

No todos los valores tiene porque llevar un suborden entre paréntesis.

Mi duda es cómo puedo ordenar esta columna por orden número del 1 al último, ya que al haber paréntesis no puedo usar Cast tipo:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        CAST( columna AS DECIMAL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que con la coma separas distintas filas:

| columna |
| --- |
| 1 (1/2) |
| 1 (2/2) |
| 2 |
| 3 (1/3) |
| 3 (2/3) |
| 3 (3/3) |
| 4 |
| 5 |

MySQL 8.0:

Con expresiones regulares puedes primero obtener la parte entera y luego el numerador de la fracción, casteas ambos a entero y ordenas primero utilizando la parte entera y luego el numerador.

```
SELECT  *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(columna, '^[0-9]*') AS SIGNED), 
         CAST(SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(columna, '\\([0-9]*'), 2) AS SIGNED);
```

De esta forma puedes expresar la fracción como un número decimal y utilizar el valor también para ordernar:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(REGEXP_SUBSTR(columna, '\\([0-9]*'), 2) /
           REGEXP_SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(columna, '[0-9]*\\)$'), '[0-9]*')
FROM mytable;
```

MySQL 5.5 o superior:

El criterio es el mismo pero sin utilizar expresiones regulares. Primero extraigo la parte entera del string y luego el numerador de la fracción, casteo ambos a entero y ordeno primero utilizando la parte entera y luego el numerador.

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(columna, ' (', 1) AS SIGNED),
    CASE WHEN POSITION('/' IN columna) > 0 THEN
            CAST(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(columna, '/', 1), POSITION('(' IN columna) + 1) AS SIGNED)
    ELSE 
        0
    END
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, me da este error: "FUNCTION team.REGEXP_SUBSTR does not exist" que versión de MySQL soporta REGEXP_SUBSTR ?? Estoy usando WAMP server

Comment: De nada @wiki! REGEXP_SUBSTR() está definida a partir de MySQL 8.0. ¿Que versión de MySQL estás utilizando? (deberías agregar una etiqueta con la versión).

Comment: Agregué una solución para MySQL 5.5 o superior (el criterio es el mismo pero sin utilizar expresiones regulares).